# MVC controller doesn't run on view load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am brand new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm really confused.  I have a controller ActionResult Method that assigns values to different items from my viewmodel.  I've done a lot of searching but I just can't figure it out.  How do you get the controller to run when the view loads, and then take a value from the method and use it in your view?  In my view I have a span and I want the value of StatusVM.StatusName from the controller method to display in a label in the view.

Here is my view:

```
@model Models.StatusViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <span>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StatusName)</span>
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Status()
{
    var Statuses = _Methods.GetStatuses();

    var AccountInfo = _Methods.GetAccount(User.AccountID) ?? new TC.DomainModels.Models.AccountModel();

    var StatusVM = new StatusViewModel();            

    //fill out the VM, you can use Mappers, you can use switch, anything to get the values form the account and tracStatusList into the VM

    var accountStatusInfo = Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusId == (int)AccountInfo.Status).FirstOrDefault();

    StatusVM.StatusName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountStatusInfo.StatusMask) ? accountStatusInfo.Status : accountStatusInfo.StatusMask;

    var carrierTerm = _accountService.GetAccountCarrierTerms(User.AccountID);
    if(carrierTerm.IsSMSNE)
    {
        StatusVM.ImagePath = accountStatusInfo.SmsneImage; 
    }                
    else
    {
         StatusVM.ImagePath = accountStatusInfo.StatusImage; 
    }


    switch (AccountInfo.Status)
    {
        case TC.DomainModels.Models.Status.Certified :
            StatusVM.ModalPath = "";
            break;
    }

    return PartialView("Navbar/nav_carrierstatus_new", StatusVM);
}
```

and here is my viewmodel:

```
public class StatusViewModel
{
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public bool UseImage { get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImagePath); } }
    public string ModalPath { get; set; }

    public StatusViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Updated Error Message:

```
{"Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information."}

{"The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."}

StackTrace:

   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_Navbar__navbar_cshtml.Execute() in c:\source code\TC Web UI Project\Branches\Branch Update TF Status Process\Views\Shared\Navbar\_navbar.cshtml:line 20
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_std_siteheader_partialview_cshtml.Execute() in c:\source code\TC Web UI Project\Branches\Branch Update TF Status Process\\Views\Shared\std_siteheader_partialview.cshtml:line 7
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\source code\TC Web UI Project\Branches\Branch Update TF Status Process\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 33
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

View that calls partial view:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div id="AccountInfoBar" class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.Partial("Navbar/nav_branding_icons")
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="acctswitch_navsection">@Html.Partial("Navbar/nav_account_switching", new List<Tcetra.Models.AccountSwitchViewModelList>())</li>
                <li id="account_navsection">@Html.Partial("Navbar/nav_account_info")</li>\
                <li id="carriersts_navsection">@Html.Action("Status", "Navbar")</li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                @Html.Partial("Navbar/nav_recent_transactions")
                @Html.Partial("Navbar/nav_cart")
                <li id="signout"><a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Login", new { area = "" })" class="HeaderSignOutLink">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: What URL are you using to access this?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make any sense.  The view *won't* "load" unless a controller action responds with it.  How are you seeing a view without invoking a controller action?

Comment: @Patrick it loads inside of another page.  I'm getting it from <li id="carriersts_navsection">@Html.Partial("Navbar/TStatus")</li>

Comment: @David I have no clue.  It's a PartialView that loads inside of another View.  When it loads it just displays the words TracStatusName

Comment: What is the name of your controller and where exactly do you plan to get "TStatus" from?

Comment: The name of my controller is AccountController.  Sorry that was a typo it should be "Navbar/Status.  Status is a view that is inside my project inside of a folder called Navbar.

Comment: You are describing a [Child Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530016/what-is-an-mvc-child-action). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction.

Comment: Please post the View that calls this partial or attempts to render the Status controller action.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I added it to the question.

Comment: I have to go back to what @Patrick asked you. What URL are you attempting to show in the browser? The exception you posted is referencing the `_layout.cshtml` file. Can you post that?

Comment: Have a look at `std_siteheader_partialview.cshtml:line 7`. This is referenced in your stack trace. You really should have a closer look at the exception message and stack trace. I think your current error is something else now.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'll have a look at it.  If I change the link back to what I originally had <li id="carriersts_navsection">@Html.Partial("Navbar/Status")</li> The error message goes away, but I don't get my data back in my view.  I'll look at the pages you mentioned though.

Comment: What is the name of the controller for the Status action? Does it live in an "Area" in ASP.NET MVC? It feels like a routing issue in MVC now.

Comment: @GregBurghardt THe name of the controller is AccountController.cs.  it is inside the Controllers folder.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I think the pages themselves live in an area.  The Status page and the navbar pages are in views/shared/navbar

Comment: No, what is the name of the controller for the **Status** method that you posted in the question?

Comment: @GregBurghardt The name of the controller is AccountController.cs

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you are looking for. From the comments to this question:

Patrick said:

> What URL are you using to access this?

hollyquinn responded:

> @Patrick it loads inside of another page. I'm getting it from `<li id="carriersts_navsection">@Html.Partial("Navbar/TStatus")</li>`

The `@Html.Partial` method **renders** a partial during the execution of the current controller action. It does not *invoke another controller action* -- and I think this is where your disconnect lies.

Instead, it looks like you want to invoke another controller action while rendering the view for the current controller action:

```
<li id="carriersts_navsection">@Html.Action("Status", "Navbar")</li>
```

You want [@Html.Action (ChildActionExtensions.Action)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx)

> Invokes the specified child action method using the specified parameters and controller name and returns the result as an HTML string.

Comment: Hi Greg.  I tried what you said, but I'm getting an error message.  An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
I tried to look it up, but I"m unsure how it relates to what's going on in my code.

Comment: @hollyquinn: Can you post the full error message, including the stack trace in your question? Something else is wrong.

Comment: I added it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your updated stack trace is showing your controller does not implement IController.  Can you post the definition of your controller ... the line should look like "public class AccountController : Controller {"