# How to add a search box like in Drupal to ASP MVC 5 app to search all site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to add a search box like therein in Drupal to ASP MVC 5 app to search all site? I am new to ASP MVC, experienced in Drupal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to design an MVC5 Global Search feature in Layout.cshtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306604/how-to-design-an-mvc5-global-search-feature-in-layout-cshtml)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below code for search options :

First you need to add reference of below JS files:

[Download JS and CSS files for Select2 Dropdown List](https://select2.github.io/)

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


Download and include in your view
```

Then Add below code on your view:

```js
$(function () {
        $("#SearchBoxddl").select2({
            placeholder: "-Select Options-"
        });
  });
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <strong class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Select Options</strong>
        <p class="form-static-control">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.SelectList, "Id", "Name"), "-Select Options-", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectBoxddl" })
        </p>
    </div>
```