# How to create a complex view model in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Creating and updating a complex view model is what I struggle with most of the time when I'm working on a web project.

For instance, I got a `PageViewModel` that takes a background image URL and a page title to pass to `_Layout.cshtml`, so

```
@model WebApplication.ViewModels.PageViewModel

<body background-image=@Model.BackgroundImageUrl>
   ...
</body
```

As for every other view model I now got 2 options:

1. Derive from `PageViewModel`
2. Create a property on `PageViewModel` to hold the specific view model (composition over inheritance etc.)

For obvious reasons I'm more inclined towards option 2. In any case, for `GET` actions I now need to initialise all the properties from `PageViewModel` as well as the properties from the view model I actually need for a particular action, e.g.

```
public PageViewModel
{
    public string BackgroundImageUrl { get; set; }
    public ContactViewModel Contact { get; set; }
}
```

is created like

```
public IActionResult Contact(int contactId)
{
   ...
   var viewmodel = new PageViewModel
   {
      BackgroundImageUrl = ...,
      ContactViewModel = new 
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

which to me is a recipe for disaster.

Things get even worse on `POST`, because ideally I will post only those fields that are relevant to the action in question, that is

```
public IActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel viewmodel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      ... (this is the easy case)
      return RedirectToAction(...)
   }

   ... (now we have a problem)
}
```

If anything goes wrong in the `POST` action I need to rebuild the entire view model graph, which is not too bad for the above example but in a real world application this gets extremely messy very fast (just think of populating drop down lists with data from a store). Controller actions are supposed to be lean, aren't they? It doesn't feel right to make the view models responsible for retrieving their own data either, so probably I should come up with a view model factory. That in turn will produce a plethora of factories, one for each view model which, again, will get messy.

I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to consider is to use a [`child action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530016/what-is-an-mvc-child-action) responsible for some portion of the layout.

So for example you could have the following child action which will be responsible for populating the background image URL:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult BackgroundImage() 
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        BackgroundImageUrl = ...
    };
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and then have a corresponding partial view:

```
@model MyViewModel

<img src="@Model.BackgroundImageUrl" alt="" />
```

which can be included in your main Layout (which in this case doesn't need a view model because the different portions of it will be assembled from the child actions):

```
<body>
    @Html.Action("BackgroundImage", "SomeController")
    ...
</body>
```

Using this approach the main action that is responsible for rendering the view doesn't need to know and assemble a complex view model. It will focus only on its specific view model.