# Asp.net MVC way to pass data to _layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I keep reading that the **MVC way to pass data** from a controller to the view is done via a ViewModel, but what about passing data to `_Layout.cshtml`, like page title, meta description, article author, etc...

What's the MVC way to pass this kind of data? Should I just use ViewBag for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data to layout that are common to all pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages)

Comment: You can use a ViewBag for page title, yes. You could also make that a model property and bind your Layout.cshtml file to that view model. You could also use session data. You have lots of options here

Comment: ViewBag is easiest. But you can also use a [Child Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530016/what-is-an-mvc-child-action).

Comment: @TheDude Are you asking about MVC 5 or MVC Core ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have few ways:

- ViewBag
- ViewData
- [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)
- Injections (example below)

**ViewBag** and **ViewData** are quite easy to use, however not always convenient.

There is one big plus - you could set/read them in one place of view and read in another - for example, you could set them in your main view and read/display them in `_lauout.cshtml`.

**View Components** are the most interesting new feature in MVC Core (in my opinion) which allows you to create UI widgets.

There is a little bit more coding for ViewComponent (you need to create controller and view), but it's flexible feature (I like it) and easy to call in a place where you need it, just

`@await Component.InvokeAsync("NameOfCOmponent")`.

**Injections** not my favorite, but sometime usfull - for example if you want display user name, you could just put the following code directly into your layout/view file:

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
@{
    var userInfo = ((await userManager?.GetUserAsync(User))?.xxx);
    // where 'xxx' is any property of ApplicationUser model
}
```

then you can use `@userInfo` in the same view to display that info.

**More information:**

- [Views Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview)
- [Passing Data to Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview#passing-data-to-views)
- [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)